# how to add new views in nop commerce?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, nopcommerce

I am on my first nopcommerce(version 2.50) application development. i want product listing in the header part o f my site. so i decided to remove menu from its div an add product listing in that section.So i created a new view named test in vies folder and called it like this

```
<div class="headermenu">
@Html.Action("Test", "Tester")
    </div>
```

but when i run the code it returns an error like

: System.Web.HttpException: The controller for path '/' was not found or does not implement IController.

ok my questions are like this

1. is this error because of i have not created a controller for for my new view.?
2. if i have to create a controller do i need to use 'with source' package or with out source package?
3. and if its with out source where can i put my controllers in it?

there is no good documentations in nopcommerce website,especially for people like me who are new to nopcommerce as well as MVC.
any help regarding this will be greatefull.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is addin already available for free. Check [this](http://www.nopcommerce.com/p/306/nop-categories-header-menu.aspx)

Dont waste your time in reinventing the wheel, just modify the javascript that comes with this addin.

Comment: this addin is not available for version 2.50.and i ned complete customisation of whole website.can you suggest any other idea.

Comment: Sorry I didnt know that the addin was not available for 2.50 since I am still sticking with 2.30 and it is working for me. Regarding your question you should have basic understanding of MVC 3.0 http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-aspnet-mvc3/cs/intro-to-aspnet-mvc-3 once you are familiar with MVC3 and the components listed here http://brandonatkinson.blogspot.co.uk/2011/08/components-used-in-nopcommerce-20.html it will be easy to start modifying their code. I would say that nopcommerce architecture is easy to understand than other CMS so Good Luck.